# Why would python CGI scripts show a webpage as plaintext after additional variables?

Tags: python, apache

I've lately been having a few issues with some of my cgi scripts once I added more variables to them. In particular, I'm currently working on remaking a page to fit within 6 variables being printed. essentially, this is the setup that causes trouble:

```
import cgi

a='''
<head>
</head>
<body>
some text'''
b=some scripts
c="<br>"          # or the likewise to separate things out a bit
d=more scripts
e="<p>"           # ^ again, this is an example, but running even this fails out for me
f='''
</body>
</html>'''
print a
print b
print c
print d
print e
print f
```

This is for example purposes, but yes, this doesn't seem to work and I'm curious if it's a limitation or what a more appropriate way to set this up might be. For more information, I figure I'll mention this is running on a cent6 system with apache 2.2.15

PS: yes I realize they are all assigned objects that I could just print them all together.

Thanks
-Jeff

Comment: Would a doctype and valid markup work? What about your cgi config in httpd.conf?

Comment: for the httpd.conf i'm using:
"Options +ExecCGI" and "AddHandler cgi-script .py"
for the directory. 

Then for the doctype checking now. sec

Comment: yeah, with doctype attempted to be declared as it would be in a regular html page it still shows this from curl -Ik and is showing up as txt:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 31 Mar 2013 08:21:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

which is funny cause if I remove like 2 or 3 of the variables and it seems to be any of them to get it down to 5 printed variables, it seems to go back to webpage. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify what content type you want the page to be.

Quoting [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#introduction):

> > The output of a CGI script should consist of two sections, separated by a blank line. The first section contains a number of headers, telling the client what kind of data is following. Python code to generate a minimal header section looks like this:

```
    print "Content-Type: text/html"     # HTML is following
    print                               # blank line, end of headers
```

Comment: When I first read this, I thought you meant putting the content type portion of the html and not the true headers to it. I'd used that type of thing to forge cookies before but never thought that would have been what was destroying my scripts. Weird that it would stop me from using my scripts only after a certain number of variables though. hahaha.